# How to get everything after string x in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string:

```
s3://tester/test.pdf
```

I want to exclude `s3://tester/` so even if i have `s3://tester/folder/anotherone/test.pdf` I am getting the entire path after `s3://tester/`

I have attempted to use the split & partition method but I can't seem to get it.

Currently am trying:

```
string.partition('/')[3]
```

But i get an error saying that it out of index.

EDIT: I should have specified that the name of the bucket will not always be the same so I want to make sure that it is only grabbing anything after the 3rd '/'.

Comment: normal string slicing would work in this case like: `string[x:]`

Comment: what output do you except in both the cases i.e. s3://tester/test.pdf and s3://tester/folder/anotherone/test.pdf  ?

Comment: The reason why `string.partition('/')[3]` is failing is because `.partition()` returns 3 items, and you are looking for the (nonexistent) 4th. Since it's a tuple with 3 items in it, the first item is accessed with [0], the second with[1], and the third with[2]).  This is what caused the out of index error.  This is only an explanation of what went wrong, the other answers actually provide solutions.

Comment: Added an edit to my original post, but to specify more here. I need to make sure that even if the s3 bucket is not named 'tester' that it still gets everything after the bucket name.  So I feel I need to have it get everything after the third '/'

Comment: Updated my answer below based on update to original question, I think my solution should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.split()`:

```
path = 's3://tester/test.pdf'
print(path.split('/', 3)[-1])
```

Output:

```
test.pdf
```

---

UPDATE: With regex:

```
import re
path = 's3://tester/test.pdf'
print(re.split('/',path,3)[-1])
```

Output:

```
test.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment - I should have been more specific.  I want to use this for multiple different s3 buckets so they will have different names.

I'm thinking the easiest way to do this is to get everything after the 3rd '/' character.  Do you know how I would do that?

So regardless of the s3 bucket it would get everything after that:
(Examples: "s3://tester/" "s3://bucket01/" "s3://bigbucket/")

Comment: @DerekEdwards Updated :)

Comment: That did it!!! Thank you Ann -- I realized that I had to add a little bit more into my argument but it all worked out.  Thanks!

Comment: Any idea on how to do this with regular expressions? I'm trying to learn regex...but it's a beast!

Comment: @DerekEdwards I added it.

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you!!

Comment: @DerekEdwards My pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `.replace`?

You could do:

```py
string = "s3://tester/test.pdf"
string = string.replace("s3://tester/", "")
print(string)
```

This will replace `"s3://tester/"` with the empty string `""`

Alternatively, you could use `.split` rather than `.partition`

You could also try:

```py
string = "s3://tester/test.pdf"
string = "/".join(string.split("/")[3:])
print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer "How to get everything after x amount of characters in python"

```
string[x:]
```

Answer (score 0):

**PLEASE SEE UPDATE**

**ORIGINAL**
Using the builtin `re` module.

```py
p = re.search(r'(?<=s3:\/\/tester\/).+', s).group()
```

The pattern uses a lookbehind to skip over the part you wish to ignore and matches any and all characters following it until the entire string is consumed, returning the matched group to the `p` variable for further processing.

This code will work for any length path following the explicit `s3://tester/` schema you provided in your question.

**UPDATE**

Just saw updates *duh*.

Got the wrong end of the stick on this one, my bad.

Below `re` method should work no matter S3 variable, returning all after third `/` in string.

```py
p = ''.join(re.findall(r'\/[^\/]+', s)[1:])[1:]
```